# Selenium python trying to extract the first selected option value from the dropdown

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to extract the first selected value from the dropdown. Not sure what I am wrong here

This is what I have tried so far:

```
currency = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("currencyid"))
currency.select_by_visible_text("AUD")

assert currency.first_selected_option().text == "AUD"
```

Here is the HTML code looks like:

[image]

This is the error I am getting, not sure how useful is this:

```
File "Test.py", line 54, in test_TestOne
    assert currency.first_selected_option().text == "USD"
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py", line 62, in first_selected_option
    for opt in self.options:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py", line 47, in options
    return self._el.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'option')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 528, in find_elements
    {"using": by, "value": value})['value']
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 494, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426923 (),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10586 x86_64)
```

Comment: `StaleElementReferenceException` means that `selenium` looked up your `element`, the `html` structure changed(is there something loading on the page still before your `select` is found?), and then you tried to use the old 'stale' element. Your best bet would probably be to wait for something indicating the page is loaded before you interact with the dropdown. To test this is the problem, put a sleep of a few seconds before this `Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("currencyid"))`, you can figure out what to wait for if that works.

Comment: Are you want to find `selected` option?

Comment: @mrfreester, not sure what is going on. I tried to add a 5 seconds sleep but it does not even wait for 5 seconds. it gives this error right away

Comment: @user7242550 where is this line at `assert currency.first_selected_option().text == "USD"`? I think you're getting your stale element there, try putting a sleep before that line.

Comment: sorry i changed my code. That means  actually means assert currency.first_selected_option().text == "AUD"

Comment: @user7242550 if it's not executing your sleep, either your code to sleep isn't actually sleeping, or it's failing before that line. If you're sure your code to sleep is correct, keep moving it up until you find out what line is really failing

Comment: gotcha. it works now. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
currency = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("currencyid"))
currency.select_by_visible_text("AUD")

assert currency.first_selected_option.text == "AUD"
```

You should use `first_selected_option` not `first_selected_option()`

Comment: and I couldn't find `assert currency.first_selected_option().text == "USD"` in your code.